# How to change cell width in tables, using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am coding, using PyQt5 and would like to know how to change the cell width in tables.
In the following source code, what should I do to change the width of the 3rd row so that all characters can fit in it.
Could anyone advise?

//Python 3

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,  QApplication, QTableView, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon,  QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1000, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("hello")

        self.initData()
        self.initUI()


    def initData(self):
        data = [["Spring", "Hiking", "I want to go on a hike to a nearby national park."], ["Summer", "Beach", "I want to go to Miami for swimming."], ["Fall", "Festival", "I want to go to see the Oktoberfest in Munich."], ["Winter", "Skiing", "I want to go on a skiing or snowboarding trip to Colorado"]]
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(4, 3)

        row = 0
        col = 0

        for col in range(3):
            for row in range(4):
                item = QStandardItem(data[row][col])
                self.model.setItem( row, col, item)

    def initUI(self):
        self.tv = QTableView(self)
        self.tv.setModel(self.model)

        self.tv.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you looking for http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setColumnWidth or maybe  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#resizeColumnToContents?

Comment: Thanks.   I tried to use "setColumnWidth()" and found it work.